# FUSE error: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I'm trying to implement the FUSE filesystem.  I am receiving this error:

> cannot access MountDir: Transport endpoint is not connected

This the relevant parts of the program. There are two directories, `MirrorDir` and `MountDir`, that exist withing the same directory as all of the code. I am calling the program like this:

```
./myFS -o nonempty -o allow_other MirrorDir MountDir
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
static struct fuse_operations xmp_oper = {
    .getattr    = xmp_getattr,
    .readdir    = xmp_readdir,
    .open       = xmp_open,
    .read       = xmp_read,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fuse_stat;
    char* mirrorDir;

    mirrorDir = malloc(sizeof(strlen(argv[argc-2]+1)));
    if (mirrorDir == NULL) {
        perror("main calloc");
        abort();
    }

    // Pull the rootdir out of the argument list and save it in my internal data
    mirrorDir = realpath(argv[argc-2], NULL);

    argv[argc-2] = argv[argc-1];
    argv[argc-1] = NULL;
    argc--;

    // turn over control to fuse
    fprintf(stderr, "about to call fuse_main\n");   
    fuse_stat = fuse_main(argc, argv, &xmp_oper, mirrorDir);
    fprintf(stderr, "fuse_main returned %d\n", fuse_stat);
    return fuse_stat;
}
```

Answer (score 177):

This typically is caused by the mount directory being left mounted due to a crash of your filesystem. Go to the parent directory of the mount point and enter `fusermount -u YOUR_MNT_DIR`.

If this doesn't do the trick, do `sudo umount -l YOUR_MNT_DIR`.

Comment: I had to sudo umount to get it to work. fusermount gave me:  entry for <mount> not found in /etc/mtab

Comment: `fusermount -u` did not work in my case, so i tried `sudo umount -l` but I get this error message: `umount: MOUNT_DIR: block devices not permitted on fs` Any ideas?

Comment: Likewise, it was the second suggestion which worked for me.

Comment: Likewise as well. `sudo umount -l YOUR_MNT_DIR` worked for me. I was using root user, which I got on with `su -`. Thank you so much :)

Comment: `umount -l` also worked for me after receiving the access error `Transport endpoint is not connected` and umount on its own complaining `Device or resource busy`.

Comment: For me only `fusermount -uz YOUR_MNT_DIR` worked (notice the extra `z`)

Comment: This alone (the -l option) worked for me when rclone lost authorization and wouldn't re-mount in the same dir due to Transport endpoint not connected and fuser/umount not working. Thanks!

Comment: Comment / solution from @farkas did solved my problem

Answer (score 26):

I mounted a ssh file system (sshfs command line) and left it mounted and I had same problem, `fusermount -u YOUR_MNT_DIR` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, I tried to mount my container using user managed identities. I kept getting `Transport endpoint is not connected` until the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` permission was added to the managed identity.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your /etc/hosts to verify it the master node is with a fully qualified name. More details in https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/Setting-the-NameNode-port-8020-to-listen-outside-of-localhost/td-p/2257 and in [How to configure hosts file for Hadoop ecosystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193051/how-to-configure-hosts-file-for-hadoop-ecosystem)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem like "Transport endpoint is not connected" or "Permission denied" when I use `rclone` to mount Microsoft OneDrive to a Ubuntu system. I am a normal user of the system, so by default my home directory is accessible only to me. When I created the mountpoint directory, it is also accessible only to me.

I finally figure out that these error messages are related to the file access privilege mode. Since I am a normal user but `fusermount` runs as root, it cannot access the mountpoint directory while mounting, and cannot access my home directory while unmounting, so it complaints. The solution is very simple: open the file access privilege of both the mountpoint directory and home directory to everyone by setting their mode bits to 777.

Answer (score 0):

A **file with unreadable characters from a Windows box** *temporarily* gave me this `endpoint not connected` error on an external USB drive each time I attempted to read it.  I could unmount and re-mount the drive to wake things up, but accessing that file (or even the directory containing it) re-broke things.

I connected the drive to a different computer and renamed the file to resolve.

---

Details

I spent a couple late-night hours lazily browsing Wikipedia and downloading the better pics to my Microsoft Surface (Win10); some had Asian and Cyrillic characters.

Not my image, but more or less this:

[image: Asian and Cyrillic filename characters]

Today I used `pscp -r -p` to push the directory to my Linux Mint box--but `pscp` threw errors on several files.  I don't explicitly recall verbatim, but this is very close if not the same:
https://superuser.com/questions/769385/pscp-and-utf-8-characters

```
"user@remote_host:/Справочник/file.txt" "E:\Справочник\file.txt"
scp: E:/??????????/file.txt: Cannot create file
```

Back at my Linux box, trying to access the directory got me the `Transport endpoint is not connected` error.  Then the entire drive became unusable--both in thunar file manager and at the CLI, with errors like "cannot get working directory" and other problems we'd expect with a damaged filesystem.

The `fusermount` command got me nowhere, but `sudo umount -l` worked several times.

Each time I un-and-re-mounted this drive (formatted exFAT), everything reverted to normal (read/write/delete worked as expected)--***until* I attempted to read/rename/remove the directory** with the unreadable (UTF-8?) characters, at which point the entire drive again became inaccessible.

I connected the drive to the WinBox and renamed the files--all better.

I could probably add a character set support, but this was the first time in 20 years I've encountered this, so I doubt I'll bother.

Jonathan Brown's answer helped me diagnose this and conclude that the simple solution of carrying the drive upstairs could be the fix.