# Error : java.net.NoRouteToHostException no route to host

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I run `select * from customers` in hive and i get the result.
Now when I run `select count(*) customers`, the job status is failed. In JobHistory I found 4 failed maps.
And in the map log file I have this :

```
2016-10-19 12:47:09,725 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-10-19 12:47:09,786 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-10-19 12:47:09,786 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2016-10-19 12:47:09,796 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2016-10-19 12:47:09,796 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1476893269614_0006, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@18aabe9c)
2016-10-19 12:47:09,878 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2016-10-19 12:47:29,958 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
2016-10-19 12:47:30,961 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:31,962 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:32,963 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:36,971 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:37,975 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:38,976 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:46,992 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:47,993 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:48,994 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:50,999 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: slave1/192.168.1.33:37159. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-10-19 12:47:51,002 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  master1/192.168.1.30 to slave1:37159 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Aucun chemin d'accès pour atteindre l'hôte cible; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:243)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Aucun chemin d'accès pour atteindre l'hôte cible
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1447)
    ... 4 more
```

And in Clouedra Manager **Hosts > slave1 > Processes > YARN Nodemanager > LogFile**  I found two worning :

**WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory :**

```
I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.33:56208, remote=/192.168.1.30:50010, for file /user/admin/.staging/job_1476893269614_0001/libjars/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.8.2.jar, for pool BP-1641388066-192.168.1.30-1476615377122 block 1073751347_10539
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient :**

```
Failed to connect to /192.168.1.30:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.33:56208, remote=/192.168.1.30:50010, for file /user/admin/.staging/job_1476893269614_0001/libjars/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.8.2.jar, for pool BP-1641388066-192.168.1.30-1476615377122 block 1073751347_10539
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.33:56208, remote=/192.168.1.30:50010, for file /user/admin/.staging/job_1476893269614_0001/libjars/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.8.2.jar, for pool BP-1641388066-192.168.1.30-1476615377122 block 1073751347_10539
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any Help please. I have been sitting with this issue for a long time now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You get a result from your first query: select * from customers because Hive doesn't use map reduce to get result

Are you sure about your hadoop configuration ?
Did you configure Hosts File ?

[How to configure hosts file for Hadoop ecosystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193051/how-to-configure-hosts-file-for-hadoop-ecosystem)

Comment: yes I do it. I have Master and two slaves(slave1,slave2), when I disable firewall in slave1, **select count(*) customers** work fine. So my problem is in the port : **slave1/192.168.1.33:port** , this port is dynamic, in this job port=37159 but in another i get new port.

Comment: How can i resolve this problem without blocked firewall

Comment: You have to unblock these specific IP. For that you must configure the firewalll on both sides to accept each other. I’d suggest you take a look at this detailed answer on how to configure iptables to allow your IP. http://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables/30031#30031

Comment: It dosen't work for me.I have the same configuration in slave1 and slave2, slave2 work fine but slave1 no.

Comment: I didn't found the solution. Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

Firewall on nodes is active.
stop firewall on node machines.

Answer (score -1):

check your hosts file and host file
it should be match other wise it will through error like you

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
======
hosts
======
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   orienit


sudo gedit /etc/hostname

hostname
========
orienit
```