# fuse Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: fuse

I have a question.when I mount my fuse ,it shows that  Transport endpoint is not connected.I don't know how to solve this problem.

**Here is my code.**

```
[root@localhost u_fs]# ./nl_fs /tmp/fuse
```

Comment: I think you should actually put some code here rather than just `enter code here[root@localhost u_fs]# ./nl_fs /tmp/fuse`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FUSE error: Transport endpoint is not connected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002539/fuse-error-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected)