# FUSE: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: c, endpoint, fuse

**Note**: I read [FUSE error: Transport endpoint is not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002539) but it doesn't help.

I'm working with the FUSE API: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse

I created a small project to test the library. The `main` looks like:

```
(...)
    struct fuse_operations operations;
    operations.open = htsfuse_open;
    operations.read = htsfuse_read;
    operations.release = htsfuse_release;
    operations.readdir = htsfuse_readdir;
    operations.getattr = htsfuse_getattr;

    int ret= fuse_main( argc-1, &argv[1], &operations,NULL );
(...)
```

my program is launched with:

```
sudo fusermount -u tmp_fuse && rm -rf tmp_fuse
mkdir -p tmp_fuse
./htsfuse config.xml ${PWD}/tmp_fuse
ls tmp_fuse
ls: cannot access 'tmp_fuse': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I also tried to

```
 sudo umount -l ./tmp_fuse
```

with/without fusermount but I got the same problem.

After my application is launched, the last line of `/etc/mtab` is

```
test.xml /path/to/tmp_fuse fuse.test.xml rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

Thank you for your help.

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it a simple memset was missing :-)

```
struct fuse_operations operations;
memset((void*)&operations,0,sizeof(struct fuse_operations));
operations.open = htsfuse_open;
operations.read = htsfuse_read;
```

Comment: `struct fuse_operations operations = {0};` does the very same thing, but is easier on the eye.